# Emacs hangs when saving new file with prettier-mode enabled

Tags: javascript, pretty-print

I'm editing JavaScript files quite a bit and I have prettier installed and `prettier-mode` and when I load files and make changes it runs, changes the layout and saves them as expected.

However, if I create a new JavaScript file with any amount of code (even something as trivial as `let A=42`) it will frequently, but not always, hang indefinitely.

If I hit `C-g`, toggle `prettier-mode`, save the file, close the buffer and reload it, then there's a tiny delay during which `*Messages*` says `Prettier syncing config`, and everything goes back to working.

However it's rather annoying that it doesn't just work in the first place. It doesn't do this on empty files but if I then add content and resave it will hang.

If I move my .emacs file out of the way and start with an empty config then I still get the same issue but in this case I have to manually enable prettier-mode since I'm missing the line "(add-hook `js-mode-hook 'prettier-mode)"

If I run with `emacs -Q` I can't even enable prettier-mode so that's not much use at all.

I'm running prettier 2.3.2 and GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2020-10-17

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, please show a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, saying what you see at each step, and what you expected to see instead. Thx.

Comment: Yes without a .emacs file but unreproducible with emacs -Q. I've edited the question with more info. Thanks.

Comment: I presume that `prettier` is a GIthub project - correct? If so, have you tried opening an issue there?

Comment: Try to give a recipe to repro the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` and then loading the `prettier` package, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had two versions of prettier-mode installed in `.emacs.d/elpa/`. As part of trying to reproduce the steps, I corrected this and the problem went away. As to how it got two different versions installed or why this would produce random hanging, I have no idea.